# JQuery: Appending to an element created in another function

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

I created a div like so:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document.createElement("div")).attr("id", "container").appendTo("body");
    });
```

and then later, dynamically I want to append some stuff to it, so in another function I call

```
$(newElement).appendTo("#container");
```

but it doesn't do anything. The div is still there, but it is empty. If I change the code to

```
$(newElement).appendTo("body");
```

it works fine. Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Here is a full example of my code:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(document.createElement("div")).attr("id", "container").appendTo("body");
            });

            function add() {
                var newElement = $(document.createElement("div")).attr("id", "inner");
                $(newElement).appendTo("#container");
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #inner{
                background-color: black;
                height: 200px;
                width:100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>       
        <script language="JavaScript" type="TEXT/JAVASCRIPT">
            add();
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: need more information perhaps... can we see your sample page?

Comment: This code looks fine. There might be some other error occurring somewhere else.

Comment: `$(document.createElement("div")).attr("id", "container")` can simply be written as `$('<div id="container"></div>')`

Comment: @Chetan: at least in jQuery 1.4, `$("<div>").attr("id", "container")` is better and faster because it calls `document.createElement()` rather than writing and parsing HTML, which is more expensive.

Comment: @Ryan: you may be having issues with browser caching of your Javascript, which is another reason to use static content versioning.

Comment: @Chetan you could even do `$('<div id="container" />')`

Comment: Actually I take it back, it looks like I and placed a hack in there to get it to work and didn't factor that out - I'll post a full example in a second.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your add() function is being called before $(document).ready();

Change it to this and it should work:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function() {
                $(document.createElement("div")).attr("id", "container").appendTo("body");
                add();
            });

            function add() {
                var newElement = $(document.createElement("div")).attr("id", "inner");
                $(newElement).appendTo("#container");
            }
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #inner{
                background-color: black;
                height: 200px;
                width:100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Which could be condensed to:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.pack.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $("<div/>", { id : "container" }).appendTo("body");
                $("<div/>", { id : "inner"}).appendTo("#container");
            });
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            #inner{
                background-color: black;
                height: 200px;
                width:100px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>       
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I see what you're saying. In reality add gets called at various points dynamically, which should work. My simplified example (which I was also using to test out various css and layout issues) is causing the problem. I guess I was under the impression that $(document).ready(); was called before it rendered the page or something. Adding <INPUT TYPE="button" VALUE="Press This" onClick="add()"> has the function working just fine on click.