# Append one dynamically-created element to another

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

I have the following prototype-based code:

```
for (j = 0; j < Math.floor(len / 2); ++j) {
    var tr = $('tr');
    var id1 = id[1] + (j * 2);
    var id2 = id[1] + (j * 2 + 1);
    // need to change the bits below here I believe
    tr.appendChild(id1.createCheckbox());
    tr.appendChild(id1.createButton());
    tr.appendChild(id2.createCheckbox());
    tr.appendChild(id2.createButton());
    t[i].appendChild(tr);
}
```

Which is prototype-based code to append the result of another function to my new `<tr>` element. The index `[i]` comes from a for-loop which envelopes this for-loop and is working fine.

My question is, how to convert this into jQuery? Basically I want to do the opposite of this case [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2197312/jquery-appending-to-an-element-created-in-another-function).

Before anyone suggests just dynamically creating a new button element, the `createButton()` and `createCheckbox()` are essential functions to create and format special buttons and also work fine.

Cheers peeps

Comment: You'll have to be more specific

Comment: I am converting some code from prototype to jQuery and found this segment. I believe the tr.appendChild(id1.createCheckbox()); should append a new checkBox thats created using the createCheckbox() function, then this product is then appended as a child element of 'tr'. It works in prototype but not in jQuery, I need to convert it but not sure how.

Answer (score 1):

1. First of all check this code again. Now it manipulates with the same element (with identifier "tr") in each iteration of loop. That's strange.
2. Find methods `createCheckbox()` and `createButton()`, they may look like

   ```
   Number.prototype.createCheckbox = function() {
       return new Element('input', {type: 'checkbox', value: 'cb' + this});
   }
   ```

   and convert them to functions. After conversion they should accept number (or maybe string if `id[]` is array of strings) as an argument and return jQuery collection with created checkbox/button:

   ```
   function createCheckbox(id) {
       return $('<input type="checkbox" value="cb' + id + '">');
   }
   ```
3. Convert your code to

   ```
   for (j = 0; j < Math.floor(len / 2); ++j) {
       var $tr = $('#tr'); // get element with id="tr"
       var id1 = id[1] + (j * 2);
       var id2 = id[1] + (j * 2 + 1);

       $tr.append(createCheckbox(id1));
       $tr.append(createButton(id1));
       $tr.append(createCheckbox(id2));
       $tr.append(createButton(id2));
       $tr.appendTo(t[i]); // note that t[i] is element, not a jQuery collection
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

not sure exactly what you asking for, maybe this:

```
for (j = 0; j < Math.floor(len / 2); ++j) {
    var tr = $('<tr></tr>');
    var id1 = id[1] + (j * 2);
    var id2 = id[1] + (j * 2 + 1);
    // need to change the bits below here I believe
    tr.append(id1.createCheckbox());
    tr.append(id1.createButton());
    tr.append(id2.createCheckbox());
    tr.append(id2.createButton());
    $(t[i]).append(tr);
}
```

Comment: sorry not solved, I don't think I've explained it as well I should have

Answer (score 0):

Try `document.createElement('tr');` instead. It should work with the rest of your code, which is using JavaScript DOM manipulation. If you'd rather switch to jQuery DOM manipulation, use MamaWalter's approach.

Comment: `$('tr')` in PrototypeJS returns DOM element with id="tr"

Comment: @Victor - thanks for that... I didn't realize prototypeJS did that. Still, based on the code, I think the OP is trying to create a new element.

Comment: new element creation looks like `new Element('tr')`